# Distribute Oracle Update ISO to Remote Servers

Tags: shell, ftp, server-administration

I need to get this oracle update installed on 30 remote servers running suse enterprise 11.  I do not work with scripting much but have a general understanding.  The distributer of the program running on the servers just sent me an iso and said I needed to burn it and send hard copy to all the stores.  I would rather not have the employees there mess with the servers so wanted to come up with a way to get this iso to them all.  Usually I just run this ftp script I have to put the files there.  However, needing to push something out to all the servers seems to becoming more and more frequent so I would like to come up with a more efficient way.

Here is my current script- actually have one for each store:

```
#! /bin/sh
HOST='IP address of the host'
USER='user'
PASSWD='password'
FILE='*.*'

ftp -nv $HOST <<END_SCRIPT
quote USER $USER
quote PASS $PASSWD
cd ftp
lcd Put
mput $FILE 
disconnect
END_SCRIPT
exit 0
```

This puts whatever files I have put into my "Put" directory into the "ftp" directory on the remote server.

My question is how could I use a serverlist.txt file for HOST= and just have it connect to the hosts in that file one after the other? Considering bandwidth, I would like it if the first task completes before the second ftp session starts. Also, I might just be a dumbass here and there is a much better way to do this that I am unaware of.  I am open to suggestions, I am just tired of being a monkey here and just waiting and watching one script runs so I can move to next store.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is there something like a shared network drive in Linux that I could share with all the external servers and just place things in there?